# Using more than one channel Relay with ESP boards starts fluctuations after 4-5 minutes

Tags: esp8266, esp32

I'm new to IoT. I'm trying to connect more than one device to relay and control via ESP board(tested with esp8266 and esp32), I'm using mqtt connecton for signaling.

**So here's whats happening**

1. If I connect just 1 relay pin to the esp8266 board, *it works fine* and I ested for 3-4 days already.
2. If I connect other pins(2+ channel relay) of the relay to the esp8266 board, I can see it working for 4-5 minutes and after that, *it starts fluctuating(relay led gets dim and you hear click sound)* and MQTT responses are not received.
3. This is *only happening when I'm connecting to external power source of 5V*. When I connect via USB from my laptop, it works fine.

**Note** :- I tested it on esp32 board as well, with a different relay, it's showing the same behaviour.

***So, I'm wondering if it is because of some power fault, do I need to power relay and board with individual 5v?***

Comment: point #3 indicates that the problem may be the external power source ... it is unable to provide enough current to energize more that one relay reliably ... please draw a wiring diagram that shows how everything is connected ... also, which relay board are you using?

Comment: Have you taken a meter and measured the input and gpio output voltages?

Comment: @hardillb, yes, i did, its giving 5 volts. One important point is, its not happening instantly, it happens only after 5-10 mins and it works fine till then.

Comment: @hardlib, i checked the output power again, i'm seeing a constant 3V. I'm hoping this is the problem. What do you guys suggest for powering esp32? I just saw a youtube video and i made it using 7805 voltage regulator and two 470 microfarad capacitor at input and output of the Voltage Regulator.

Comment: That's a question for https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @hardlib, Oh okay, i'll reachout to them then. Thanks a lot. Just one small doubt, did you guys ever face any issue like, you 7805 IC is faulty or your meter is not showing correct output. I googled today a lot of thing and tried various ways of debugging, it was constantly giving 3V